# How to pass application.properties to SpringBoot app in Docker container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, file, parameter-passing, docker-container

Assume we have a simple `Dockerfile` where `my_sb_app.jar` is a SpringBoot application:

```
FROM bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:11.0.9-12    
WORKDIR /app    
COPY target/my_sb_app.jar /app    
EXPOSE 8080    
ENTRYPOINT java -jar my_sb_app.jar
```

I would like to pass custom `app.properties` on each run

```
docker run  my_image_name  /somewhere/on/my/host/app.properties
```

so the expected final command (inside the container) could be identical to the following

`java -jar my_sb_app.jar --spring.config.location=%%file_with_contents_of_app.properties%%`

What is the standard way of passing a file into a Docker container? 
How the Docker image sould be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to pass files from host to the container is with volumes:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

In your example:

```
docker run -v /somewhere/on/my/host/app.properties:/opt/app.properties my_image_name 

java -jar my_sb_app.jar --spring.config.location=/opt/app.properties
```